# is there a way to consistently have dot subgraph order controlled?

Tags: graphviz, dot

The 'constraint=false'sometimes' allows the clusters to get out of order, even when doing so, causes longer edges. I wish to both have all subgraph clusters line up 'and' keep the order of the subgraph clusters intact. (which in my case, since I alway will only connect the edge to an node neighboring cluster, will result in edge that don't cross over an intervening subgraph. Sometimes it works as expected, but in the example I am posting, you can see the '2nd' subgraph for some reason shows up in the third position (which causes the links to go farther than they need to.)

Is there a way to achieve both the lining up of all the tops of the subgraphs 'and' maintaining a specific order of subgraphs left to right?

I have read many posts, and have tried many of the things suggested, but I can't seem to find a combination that works.  When constraint=true, the 'order' seems to be correct, but the alignment is wrong. When constraint=false... The alignment is correct and 'sometimes' the order is correct, but other like the example posted, the order is invalid.

```
digraph G {
ranksep=.05;
splines=line;

subgraph cluster_1 {
label="1";
choice0_0[label="1"];
choice0_1[label="2"];
choice0_2[label="3"];
choice0_0 -> choice0_1 -> choice0_2 [style="invis"];
}
subgraph cluster_2 {
label="2";
choice1_0[label="1"];
choice1_1[label="2"];
choice1_2[label="3"];
choice1_0 -> choice1_1 -> choice1_2 [style="invis"];
}
subgraph cluster_3 {
label="3";
choice2_0[label="1"];
choice2_1[label="2"];
choice2_2[label="3"];
choice2_0 -> choice2_1 -> choice2_2 [style="invis"];
}
edge[constraint=false];
choice0_2 -> choice1_1;
choice1_1 -> choice2_2;
}
```

dot -Tps x.gv -o x.ps

(where x.gv contains the code pasted above)

No errors are displayed when this is run, but this example the order of the 2nd and 3rd subgraph is swapped.

Comment: P.S. This issue can be duplicated by pasting the code into https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/